# The minimum perimeter and maximum height of a triangle under constraints

Tags: geometry, triangles

I'm developing a web application that consists of a calculator triangles. Although I am not a mathematician, with paper, derive and Geogebra I managed to get a lot of formulas to calculate a triangle with the minimum number of data possible. Maybe some is unpublished, and limits to be introduced only correct data.

I do not get the following formulas :

- The minimum perimeter of any triangle (abc) once known the heights corresponding to the $a$ and $b$-sides.
- The maximum height corresponding to the side $b$ of any triangle (abc) once known the value of its perimeter and height corresponding to the $a$-side.

I am looking for an answer in a way that could be implemented in php (programming language).

Comment: This may not be the right place to get help implementing something in PHP... I'd try to help with the formulas, but I don't think I understand the question.

Comment: (This question was originally Google-translated from Spanish; I edited to clarify the language in some places, but not in the bullet points.)

Comment: I do not need help in php, I just wanted to say that I can only use simple mathematical functions such as sin, arctan, pow ... standars in all basic languages like java c .....

Comment: Let $a,b,c=a-b$ the vectors of the triangle sides. The first then is $\min |a|+|b|+|a-b|$ when $b^2-((a\cdot b)/|a|)^2=h_1^2, a^2-((a\cdot b)/|b|)^2=h_2^2$ given. [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minimize+%7Cx%7C%2B%7Cy%7C%2Bsqrt%28x%5E2%2By%5E2-2z%29+when+x%5E2-%28z%2Fy%29%5E2%3Da%3E0+and+y%5E2-%28z%2Fx%29%5E2%3Db%3E0) could not.

Answer (score 3):

In the first case, we may assume that the angle between the $a$ and $b$ sides is $\theta$. Then:
$$ h_a = b\sin\theta,\qquad  h_b = a\sin\theta \tag{1}$$
and by the [law of cosines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines):
$$ c^2 = a^2+b^2-2ab\cos\theta = \frac{h_a^2+h_b^2-2h_a h_b\cos\theta}{\sin^2\theta}\tag{2}$$
so we just have to find the stationary points of the function:
$$ p(\theta) = \frac{h_a+h_b+\sqrt{h_a^2+h_b^2-2h_a h_b\cos\theta}}{\sin\theta}\tag{3}$$
over the interval $(0,\pi)$ by solving $p'(\theta)=0$ or $\frac{d}{d\theta}\frac{1}{p(\theta)}=0$. This leads to a cubic equation in $\cos\theta$, hence the problem, in general, is not solvable with straightedge and compass. When the perimeter reaches it minimum we have that $\cos\theta$ is the only root in $(-1,1)$ of:

> $$ q(z) = 1 - \left(2 \frac{h_a}{h_b} + 1 + 2 \frac{h_b}{h_a}\right) z + 3  z^2 + 
>   z^3. \tag{4}$$

The second problem is just the dual problem of the first one.

Comment: In the first case i need maximun value of p but only i have ha and hb values no an angle.

Comment: the value is a; "The maximum height corresponding to the side b of any triangle (abc) known the value of its perimeter and height corresponding to the side a."

Comment: @Jesús: it is obvious that you have no angle, but $(3)$ just shows that the perimeter depends on the angle between $a$ and $b$. So by differentiating $p(\theta)$ and solving $p'(\theta)=0$ you can find the optimal angle.

Comment: You can use http://triancal.esy.es to try and draw values,

Comment: I am not a mathematician, can you help me to find this formula?

Comment: @Jesús: I have updated my answer. Now you just have to solve $q(z)=0$ with the general formula for cubic equations: that gives $\cos\theta$ in the stationary point. By plugging back in $\cos\theta$ and $\sin\theta=\sqrt{1-\cos^2\theta}$ in $(3)$ you may find the minimum perimeter.

Comment: I dont undestand your anwer, i don't have q and z. With GeoGebra i can obtain this value: http://tube.geogebra.org/student/m1176787

Comment: @Jesús, I gave you the polynomial is needed to solve the problem. You just have to find its real root. I do not think I will spend more time on this.

Comment: I find two possible areas (t1 and t2) for two heights (x, y) and perimeter (p)... v1=(x*x*(y*y+p*p)+3*p*p*x*y+p*p*y*y)/((12*p*(x+y))) .... v2=sqrt(abs(x^4*(y*y+p*p)^2+6*p*p*x^3*y^3+p*p*x*x*y*y*(2*y*y-p*p)+p^4*y^4))/((6*p*(x+y))) .... v3=-asin((2*x^6*(y*y+p*p)^3+18*p*p*x^5*y^3*(y*y+p*p)+3*p*p*x^4*y*y*(2*y^4+10*p*p*y*y-p^4)+18*p^4*x^3*y^5+3*p^4*x*x*y^4*(2*y*y-p*p)+2*p^6*y^6)/((2*abs((x^4*(y*y+p*p)^2+6*p*p*x^3*y^3+p*p*x*x*y*y*(2*y*y-p*p)+p^4*y^4))^3/2))))/(3) .... t1=v1-v2*sin(A60+v3) .... t2=v1+v2*sin(v3) .... A60=1.0471975511965976  .... I don't have any area values.